# Is there any way to create buttons in a for loop with the same function but with different attributes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create several buttons so each one will activate the same function but with changing attributes. What probably happens, is that the value that I take from the for loop is the last one it generates. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

def add(num):
    print(num)
    return num + 5

num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    Button(root, text=str(num_list[i]), command=lambda: print(add(num_list[i]))).place(x=350 ,y=250+i*20)

root.mainloop()
```

In the following code, no matter what button you click it will always send 5 as the value of I (the last value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a variable to the lambda call, like so:

```
Button(root, text=str(num_list[i]), command=lambda i=i: print(add(num_list[i]))).place(x=350 ,y=250+i*20)
```

That i=i will make the program work how you want it, as it will make the function take the value of i when the button was created.